# I tried adding column names to a dataframe and it deleted all data i added to it

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

This is the code I used. I first read the data to variable 'dbs' and then converted it into a DataFrame named 'dtabse' with column names 'Username' and 'Password'.

```
dbs = pd.read_csv('pass_users.txt', header=None)

dtabse= pd.DataFrame(dbs, columns=['Username', 'Password'])
```

But upon running it, all my data turned into NaN

The image linked below shows the output I'm getting

[image]

Any help will be appreicated.
Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `dbs = pd.read_csv('pass_users.txt', header=None)` already gives you a dataframe, so your second line isn't necessary. What you'd need to do to change the column names would be

```
dbs.columns = ['Username', 'Password']
```

In fact, I think you can do this immediately

```
dbs = pd.read_csv('pass_users.txt', names=['Username', 'Password'])
```

Comment: Neither of your suggestions work. The first one gave me this error:

IndexError: only integers, slices (`:`), ellipsis (`...`), numpy.newaxis (`None`) and integer or boolean arrays are valid indices

The second one gave this error:
TypeError: read_csv() got an unexpected keyword argument 'columns'

Comment: I edited my answer. Sorry for the second mistake. As for your first error, I don't know what could be causing it. That is a valid way to change column names as long as `dbs` is a dataframe and has the same number of columns as the list with the new column names. You could be making a mistake somewhere else.

Comment: thank you, i actually added the column headings to the source file itself. i think ur script is correct but dont know why it didnt work on mine. thanks anyway!

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Camilo's answer, if you have multiple columns and only want to keep a selection:

```
dbs = pd.read_csv('pass_users.txt', header=None)
dbs = dbs[['Username', 'Password']]   # Enter columns to keep
```